# Limits in functions from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Good evening,
I would like tips / methods for calculating limits of functions of $\mathbb R ^ 2 \in \mathbb R$.

The squeeze theorem is sometimes a problem for me to set up because I do not know how to put in order this new type of functions in the good way, it is necessary that $f (x, y) <g (x, y) <h (x, y)$ but I must make sure this is true for all $x$ and all $y$?

Concerning the formal definition, making $\lvert \lvert x - x_0 \rvert \rvert$ (where $x$ and $x_0$ are in $\mathbb R^2$) appear in the expression $\lvert f(x) -l \rvert$ is sometimes difficult. Obviously, my teacher has the bad habit of giving the simplest examples in the world by looking for example at the limit when $(x, y)$ tends to $(1,0)$ of a function where there is already $\sqrt {(x-1) ^ 2 + y ^ 2}$ which is not very beneficial for the students.

I have heard of switching to polar. The course on these functions being discovered today, I have not yet seen this method but if it is really essential and useful I would like to know what it consists of.

As an example I am interested in the limit when (x, y) goes to $(0,1)$ of $f (x, y) = \frac {y} {x ^ 2} e ^ {\frac {- y} {x ^ 2}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat it as a single limit (as opposed to $x\rightarrow x_0$ and $y\rightarrow y_0$ independently) then you need to account for *all possible* sequences that converge to $(x_0,y_0)$. The limit of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ only exists if the images of all such sequences converge to the same value.

This is because function limits are defined in terms of *universal qualification* of points arbitrarily close to the limit point. This doesn't make much of a difference in $\mathbb{R}$ because you can only approach a point from 2 different directions, but in higher dimensions there are infinite directions of approach.

---

If you *know* that the limit exists and you'd just like to compute it, then you can use *any* parametric function $z(n)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)$, as long as $f$ is defined for every $z(n)$. Note that it's up to you how to use $n$; you could do $n\rightarrow\infty$ or $n\rightarrow0$. It just needs to match how you use $n$ in $z(n)$. ($n\rightarrow\infty$ is more common, such as in real-analysis proofs that use convergent sequences.)

You can also use this to prove that the limit *doesn't* exist, by creating a sequence where $f$ doesn't converge, or two sequences where $f$ converges to different values.

In your example, fixing $x=0$ is only one possible way to approach $(0,1)$. You also need to try other sequences as a sanity check, such as $\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{cos}(n),1+\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{sin}(n)\right)$.

Note that there's nothing special about choosing the sequence, as long as it converges to $(x_0,y_0)$. The goal is to find a sequence that makes the computation of (or the proof of non-existence of) the limit convenient.

You also mentioned polar coordinates. If you used something like $\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{cos}(\theta),\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{sin}(\theta)\right)$, then you can leave $\theta$ unspecified to show that the angle of approach doesn't affect the result.

---

Here is a specific example of a limit that appears to exist if you only look at one sequence approaching the limit point.

Let $f(x,y)=\mathrm{tanh}\left(\frac{1}{x+y}\right)$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$.

- With $z(n)=\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$, $f(z(n))=\mathrm{tanh}\left(n\right)\rightarrow 1$.
- With $z(n)=\left(\frac{1}{n},-\frac{2}{n}\right)$, $f(z(n))=\mathrm{tanh}\left(-n\right)\rightarrow -1$.

Since the images of the two sequences don't converge to the same value, that means that the limit at $(0,0)$ doesn't exist.